# Heroku failed to push some refs on Ruby on Rails Proj

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Im just new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails. I got an error shown below when I was following instructions from Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial:
[enter image description here][1]

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ancient-sands-19579.git'
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU3Zm.png
Ive tried most of solutions I can find on the Internet including:

- try pull heroku master(This returns me an error that couldn't find remote ref master)
- git switch -b newbranch
  git push heroku newbranch(This gives me no error. The problem is Heroku's welcome page is still there. It makes no difference when I refresh the page with a new route and action added.)

Ive beem stuck here for hours and Im getting frustrated :(
I will appreciate all of you guys who try to get me out of this....

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165028/newbie-in-heroku-error-when-push-my-app-to-heroku/8171155#8171155 .

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will try those solutions!