# Heroku rails 6 Precompiling assets stop with no error information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, webpacker

I am suddenly unable to deploy on Heroku. When I try to deploy my rails app, I encounter the following issue:

```
remote:        Compiling... 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to my-app.        
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git
! [remote rejected]     my-app -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git'
```

It can be see that the deployment process stops at the compiling stage without displaying any "Precompiling assets failed" message or other error message. When I run "rake assets:precompile" locally, the compilation is successful.

I have absolutely no clue how to interpret the error, some help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for reading!

Comment: This has nothing to do with pre-compiling assets this failure occurs trying to push to heroku and is generally caused by an unsupported application: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216586/git-heroku-pre-receive-hook-declined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165028/newbie-in-heroku-error-when-push-my-app-to-heroku/8171155#8171155